# Date not convert in AM/PM Format in swift

Tags: swift

I need to date and time with my own format like time in AM/PM (12 hours).

```
extension Date {
func getStringFromDateWithUTCFormat() -> ObjTimeStamp {
                
        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
        
        // Get Date
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" //"MMM dd,yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: self)
        
        // Get Time
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
        let time = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: self)
        
        return ObjTimeStamp.init(date: date, time: time, timeStamp: self)
    }   
}
```

## Update

Calling function

```
self.currentDate = Date()
let objTimeStamp = currentDate.getStringFromDateWithUTCFormat()
```

> Perfect work when device time in 12-hour format when I try to change device time in 24-hour formate then given wrong time format.

[image]

Comment: How are you calling your function? I tried this and it is giving me proper answer.

Comment: Yes, Just wait, I'll update in my question.

Comment: @SahilManchanda please check my question, I have added function calls.

Comment: Try this http://tpcg.io/9DwGXKDo

Comment: When I try to change my iPhone time in 24 hours then wrong output like mentioned in the screenshot

Comment: My code is perfectly works in a 12-hour format in the device.

Comment: Sorry I don't have device right now. will check in the eve. though system time format shouldn't affect the output.

Comment: This code works fine on my Mac when I run it in a playground and I have a 24h clock format. Have you tried with setting the locale of the date formatter? Like `dateFormatterPrint.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your dateFormatter locale to en-US then try to convert, it's works for me when iPhone's time format is 24 hour:

```
let date = Date()              
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let time12 = formatter.string(from: date)
print(time12)
```

output:

```
01:37 PM
```

Comment: What was the difference between your code and my code?

Comment: you have used "self" I have used  "Date()"

Comment: When I try to change my iPhone time in 24 hours then wrong output like mentioned in the screenshot.

Comment: That's why I create a date extension. You can check it in my question.

Comment: I have changed my answer, previously I have tested with playground but now I have tested with iPhone